# better way of handling list of dict or improving my code

Tags: python

I have a dict

```
my_dict =
    { '123@com' : [ { 'event': 'event1', 'oldval' = 1, 'newval = 2}, { 'event': 'event2', 'oldval' = 11, 'newval': 22}, { 'event': 'event3', 'oldval' = 33, 'newval': 44}] 
    {'1234@com' : { 'event1': 'oldval': 45, 'newval': 66},
    {'12345@com': [ {'event':'event2', 'oldval': 77, 'newval': 99}, { 'event': 'event3', 'oldval': '99', 'newval': 100'}]
```

So basically my goal is to build a list

```
 [ ['123@com', (2,1,True), (22,11, True), (44,33,True)], ['1234@com', (66,45,True), ('','',False),('','',False)], ['12345@com', ('',''False), (99,77,True), (100,99)]]
```

So my goal is to capture the value if event is changed and get the values and marked as true.

So the code which I am writing is as follows:

```
for key,value in my_dict.items():
  if str(my_dict).find('event1') >- 1 or str(my_dict).find('even2') > 1 or str(my_dict).find('event3') > -1: 
  tmp_list = []
  tmp_list.append(key)
  if type(value) is dict:
    if value['event'] == 'event1': 
       @ get all the value and append to tmp_list
    if value['event'] == 'event2':
      @ do the same thing as above
  else:
     for val in value:
      if val['name'] == 'event':
        @ do the same stuff. 
      @do the same stuff again for rest of event.
```

So basically I am able to achieve my goal by following the above code pattern.

So any one can help me out in coding better,I will really appreciate it.
I don't like the way I am coding.

Thanks

Comment: So you really like starting a sentence with "So", right?

Comment: Also, neither of the two snippets you posted are actually valid Python, so how about you post your real code so we can find a correct answer for you?

Answer (score 0):

Having heterogeneous lists like `['123@com', (2,1,True), (22,11, True), (44,33,True)]` is a code smell.  It almost always means that you're trying to do too much with simple data types, and would probably be better served by actually using a class.  Assuming python 2.x:

```
class Event(object):
    def __init__(self, event, oldval, newval):
        self.event = event
        self.oldval = oldval
        self.newval = newval

class EventThing(object):
    def __init__(self, key, event_list):
        self.key = key
        self.event_list = [Event(**e) for e in event_list]

    def produceCondensedList(self):
        return [(e.oldval, e.newval, True) for e in self.event_list]

thing_list = [EventThing(key, event_list) for key, event_list in my_dict.items()]
```

It's not exactly the same as the example you gave, but without knowing more about your exact use case, it's hard to suggest precise answers.  The above should be enough to at least get you started.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way I could think of coding this.

```
def value_finder(val):
    return lambda ev,li: next((di[val] for di in li if di['event']==ev),'')

def event_finder(ev,li):
    return any(di['event']==ev for di in li)

def tuple_return(ev,li,nv,ov):
    return (nv(ev,li),ov(ev,li),event_finder(ev,li))

def main(my_dict):
    lis = []
    nv = value_finder('newval')
    ov = value_finder('oldval')
    events = ['event1','event2','event3']
    for key,value in my_dict.items():
        temp_list = [key]
        temp_list += [tuple_return(ev,value) for ev in events]
        lis.append(temp_list)
    print lis

my_dict = {'123@com':[{'event':'event1','oldval':1,'newval':2},
                      {'event':'event2','oldval':11,'newval':22},
                      {'event':'event3','oldval':33,'newval':44}],
          '1234@com':[{'event':'event1','oldval':45,'newval':66}],
          '12345@com':[{'event':'event2','oldval': 77,'newval': 99},
                      {'event':'event3','oldval':'99','newval':100}]}
main(my_dict)
```